# "on dirait qu'il n'en a pas envie" Why is en used here?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

"En" means of it, but that translation does not fit here.

Is this an idiom.

And also can someone give me a detailed explanation on how to use "en" and "y"; they are very confusing.